# understanding the meaning of this sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does this sentence mean?

> She has the ability to keep the emotions, triumphs and fears of her characters on a human scale.

Comment: I guess it's describing a writer, and it does appear to be a bit garbled. Which part are you having problems with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She depicts her characters' feelings realistically, rather than exaggerating them, turning them into great dramatic displays, as Shakespeare did with King Lear and Hamlet, or like a comic book villain who turns a childhood disappointment into a campaign to take revenge on the entire world.

Comment: your answers was really clear for me that i got my answer thanks